# No se muestran los valores de consulta en BlComboBox. QT4

Tags: c++, qt

No consigo que un BlCombobox me muestre los valores de una consulta. Lo he hecho como otros que hay en el código y nada, no se que puede pasar.

## intervalo_fechas.h

```
#ifndef INTERVALOFECHAS_H
#define INTERVALOFECHAS_H

#include "blcrear.h"
#include "tsystem.h"
#include "blhelp.h"
#include "pdefs_plugin_pro.h"
#include "ui_intervalo_fechasbase.h"
#include "blgenericcomboboxdelegate.h"
#include "blcomboboxdelegate.h"

class PLUGIN_PRO_EXPORT IntervaloFechas
        : public BlCrear
        , public Ui::IntervaloFechasBase
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    IntervaloFechas();
    ~IntervaloFechas();
    //void combo();
    void on_mui_aceptar_clicked();
public slots:
    void imprimir_resumen_global();

private slots:
    void on_mui_cancelar_clicked();
};

#endif
```

## intervalo_fechas.cpp

```
#include "intervalo_fechas.h"

IntervaloFechas::IntervaloFechas()
{
    BL_FUNC_DEBUG;
    try{

        setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        setupUi(this);

        mui_id_tipo_proto->setMainCompany(mainCompany());
        mui_id_tipo_proto->setQuery("SELECT id,concepto FROM pro.tipo_proto");
        mui_id_tipo_proto->setFieldId("id");
        mui_id_tipo_proto->m_valores["concepto"]= "";
        mui_id_tipo_proto->setAllowNull(true);

    } catch(...) {
        g_s->msgError(_("No se pudo abrir la ventana %1.").arg(metaObject()->className()), this);
    }

}

IntervaloFechas::~IntervaloFechas()
{
    BL_FUNC_DEBUG;
   // En el caso de querer usar esta venta para otros estados, seria ahcer un CASE y en el Ui, pasarle valor donde pone "Revisar" para que ponga el estado del case en el label.

}
void IntervaloFechas::on_mui_aceptar_clicked()
{
    g_s->msgError("generar informe");
    close();
}


void IntervaloFechas::on_mui_cancelar_clicked()
{
    close();
}
```

## intervalo_fechas.ui

```
<item>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>50</width>
            <height>50</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Tipo</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="BlComboBox" name="mui_id_tipo_proto" native="true"/>
        </item>
        <item>
         <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeType">
           <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>10</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </item>
```

## Valores Query:

```
1;"Prototipo"
2;"Madera"
3;"Metacrilato"
4;"Utillajes"
5;"Test Prototipos"
```

Desde el designer, no me deja hacer promote a nada, y no me saca ningún error ni por debug ni por consola.

En los otros ejemplos de Blcombobox delegate que hay en el código, no se hace ningún promote ni nada. No entiendo como no me muestra los valores en el desplegable.

Cualquier ayuda sera bien recibida, mil gracias.

Comment: Voy a probar pasando valores a QcomboBox... está igual que el resto de BlComboBox y nada, el contenido del desplegable es vacio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está solucionado me faltaba añadir en el cpp donde declaro el blcombobox la línea     mui_id_tipo_proto->setId("");